# Excel matching duplicates across multiple columns with unorganized data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got two lists each containing the following parameters: `Serial number`, `name of product` and `name of the owner`.

I wish to be able to compare the two lists to be able to mark duplicates where a duplicate must have all three categories identical. One list usually has more lines of items and the lists are not organized.

Usually I would use this formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A:$A)=0, "  ", " V ")`

to check unorganized values across one parameter but I am not sure how to do this for all three parameters. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sample data like this:

[image]

The formula is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH(E2&F2&G2,$A$2:$A$8&$B$2:$B$8&$C$2:$C$8,0),1)>0,FALSE)
```

Which:

- takes the combo of the row of the list you are checking `E2&F2&G2`
- tries to `MATCH` it against all the rows of the other list `$A$2:$A$8&$B$2:$B$8&$C$2:$C$8`
- returns `TRUE` for a match - using `INDEX` to pull out the result
- returns `FALSE` for an error in the `MATCH` (`#VALUE!` error)

Comment: Is there a way for it to automatically move line after line and check all of the list E F G (in the example) ? Instead of checking each line individually  by moving the E2 F2 G2 values ? @Robin

Comment: You can copy the formula in column H down as much as you need - is that what you mean?

Comment: The formula in column H holds for one line, meaning that when run it checks if the second list (ABC) holds the values of E2 F2 and G2. Instead I would like it to run on all of the first list (EFG) instead of me needing to check line after line if they are within the second list.      
        
Something in the sorts of 
$E2:$E8&F2:$F8&G2:G8 Is something like that possible?  
       

On a different note I wanted to say thanks for all the help!

Comment: Thanks for all the help Robin, I have a quick question in case you are still following this thread! Could I instead of making it a bool True or False answer say something like
"If match(print P4)"
As in that instead of it printing "TRUE" when there is a match it will print some info about the item

Comment: Just wrap the `INDEX` function inside another `IF` and then you can do something - e.g. `=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(MATCH(E6&F6&G6,$A$2:$A$8&$B$2:$B$8&$C$2:$C$8,0),1)>0,"foo","bar"),"bar")` - you can replace `"foo"` and `"bar"` with other functions and lookups.

Comment: Sort of a silly question.
I am using this forumla for a different kind of work where I need to match serial numbers between columns but I need to take out information from the line I reached while searching - The line should look something like this :
`=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(MATCH(A1,$J$1:$J$8,0),1)>0,$H$1:$H$8,"Not included"),"Not")`
As in I want the information out of the H column in the line where A is matched with J